# How can I do an explode in GridView in Yii framework, PHP?

Tags: php, gridview, yii

This is my query:

```
SELECT p.name AS p_name, p.id AS pid, p.description AS p_description, 
GROUP_CONCAT(r.id SEPARATOR ',') AS rids, 
GROUP_CONCAT(r.name SEPARATOR ',') AS rnames
FROM `profiles` p
LEFT JOIN rights r ON p.id = r.profile_id 
WHERE p.app_id = 8
GROUP BY p_name
```

and this is the GridView:

```
$this->widget('GridView', array(
            'dataProvider' => $apps_list,
            'id' => 'my_grid_view',
            //'filter' => $filtersForm,
            'itemsCssClass'=>'table',
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'Rights',
                    'type'    => 'raw',
                    'value'   => 'CHtml::tag("div",array(),"<span>".$data["rnames"]."</span>")',
                    // 'value'=> 'CHtml::encode($data["rnames"])',
                    'filter'  => '',
                ),
            ),  

        ));
```

This generates a column like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to create some checkboxes for each right(CanCreate,CanUpdate,CanAccess) if there exists. To do that I need to do an `explode("^^",$data["rnames"])`. How can write this explode in my gridview ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous function in your value:

```
'value' => function($data) {
    //do here whatever you want
    return CHtml::tag("div",array(),"<span>".$data["rnames"]."</span>");
}
```